# Alternative solution for :focus on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, safari, focus

I'm struggling to find a different solution for `:focus` when clicked on a button, as [Safari doesn't support :focus on buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus).

I have a field of 16 buttons, which should change colours when clicking on it and loose it when different button is clicked.

I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/demian1985/va2omn35/31/) to show the events. `toggleClass` is not the right solution and would like to avoid `:focus`.

**Current JS code:**

```
$(".tbl-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".tbl-button:focus").addClass("table-btn-color");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your css declaration from `.table-btn-color` to `.tbl-button:active`.

but if you want to use jQuery you can do it like this

```
$(".tbl-button").on("mousedown", function() {
  $(this).addClass("table-btn-color");
}).on('mouseup', function(){
  $(this).removeClass("table-btn-color");
});
```

In order to retain the class on the selected element you can do it like so:

```
$(".tbl-button").on("mousedown", function() {
  // remove the class form all .tbl-button elements
  $(".tbl-button").removeClass("table-btn-color");
  // add it to the currently pressed element
  $(this).addClass("table-btn-color");
})
```

Comment: In this case the colour doesn't focus, only during the click. Not when the button has been clicked. `:active` is unfortunately not the alternative for `:focus`

Comment: @Demian didn't quite get the question, so I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replace this: 
    $(".tbl-button:focus").addClass("table-btn-color");

by this 
    $( document.activeElement ).addClass("table-btn-color");

Comment: There is no change; same result; focus stays on the buttons when clicking on a different button.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class `table-btn-color` to `table-btn-color:active`